# how to know which all child objects has relationship with opportunity in salesforce. (Opportunity is parent)

Tags: relationships, childrelationship, metadata-relationship, object-relational-mapping

***I need to know which all objects have parent as Opportunity. Is there any easy way to get the details?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) class to access any SObject parent and/or child objects. Here is a print out of child objects of the `Opportunity` SObjectType.

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobResult = Opportunity.SObjectType.getDescribe();
for (Schema.ChildRelationship childRel : sobResult.getChildRelationships()) {
    System.debug('Child Object: ' + childRel.getChildSObject());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Opportunity.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getChildRelationships();
Edit: Ouh, @TSmith answered before me ;D Gj!

Comment: hey David! Welcome to SFSE! thanks for taking the time to provide answers, however, if you could please avoid posting 1 liners and help provide an explanation as to "why" trying this answers the OP's question, it would be more helpful to the community and better received overall. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code to fetch the child objects which have the opportunity as parent object

```
String parentObjectName = 'Opportunity';  
Map<string,string> objectRelationshipMap = new Map<string,string>();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
for(String ss1: schemaMap.keyset()){
    Schema.SObjectType objToken=schemaMap.get(ss1);
    if(ss1.equalsignorecase(parentObjectName)){
        //find details about sobject
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objDescribe=objToken.getdescribe();
        List<Schema.ChildRelationship> childRelationshipList = objDescribe.getChildRelationships();
        system.debug('******childRelationshipList.size():'+childRelationshipList.size());
        for(Schema.ChildRelationship ss:childRelationshipList){
            string RelationshipName=ss.getRelationshipName();
            string childObjectName = string.valueof(ss.getChildSObject());
            string childFieldToken = string.valueof(ss.getField());
            system.debug('*********childFieldToken:'+ childFieldToken);
            system.debug('*********childObjectName:'+childObjectName); 
            system.debug('*********RelationshipName:'+RelationshipName);
            objectRelationshipMap.put(childObjectName+'.'+childFieldToken,RelationshipName);
        }
    }
}
system.debug('***objectRelationshipMap.size():'+objectRelationshipMap.size());
system.debug('***objectRelationshipMap:'+objectRelationshipMap);
```